# Slow Mysql Inner joins with multiple OR

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, query-optimization

I'm helping a friend with an e-commerce site. He has options for users to select different colours, styles, use and type of the products he's selling. The query the adds the following to the query:

```
INNER JOIN tbl_coloursProducts col ON ( p.product_id = col.productID AND (col.colourID = 2 OR col.colourID = 3 OR col.colourID = 5 OR col.colourID = 8 OR col.colourID = 10)) 
INNER JOIN tbl_useProducts tbluse ON ( p.product_id = tbluse.productID AND (tbluse.useID = 15 OR tbluse.useID = 16 OR tbluse.useID = 17 OR tbluse.useID = 18)) 
INNER JOIN tbl_styleProducts style ON ( p.product_id = style.productID AND (style.styleID = 39 OR style.styleID = 44)) 
INNER JOIN tbl_typeProducts type ON ( p.product_id = type.productID AND (type.typeID = 46 OR type.typeID = 48 OR type.typeID = 50))
```

The query loads fast enough when only a few options are selecting, but some users are selecting multiple or each which is causing the query to run in excess of 30 seconds and timing out.

Without altering the table structure is there a better way to optimise the query?

This is the full query:

```
SELECT *, 
       p.product_id, 
       Coalesce((SELECT p2sp.price 
                 FROM   ab_product_specials p2sp 
                 WHERE  p2sp.product_id = p.product_id 
                        AND p2sp.customer_group_id = '1' 
                        AND ( ( p2sp.date_start = '0000-00-00' 
                                 OR p2sp.date_start < Now() ) 
                              AND ( p2sp.date_end = '0000-00-00' 
                                     OR p2sp.date_end > Now() ) ) 
                 ORDER  BY p2sp.priority ASC, 
                           p2sp.price ASC 
                 LIMIT  1), p.price) AS final_price, 
       pd.name                       AS name, 
       m.name                        AS manufacturer, 
       ss.name                       AS stock, 
       (SELECT Avg(r.rating) 
        FROM   ab_reviews r 
        WHERE  p.product_id = r.product_id 
        GROUP  BY r.product_id)      AS rating, 
       (SELECT Count(rw.review_id) 
        FROM   ab_reviews rw 
        WHERE  p.product_id = rw.product_id 
        GROUP  BY rw.product_id)     AS review 
FROM   ab_products p 
       LEFT JOIN ab_product_descriptions pd 
              ON ( p.product_id = pd.product_id 
                   AND pd.language_id = '1' ) 
       LEFT JOIN ab_products_to_stores p2s 
              ON ( p.product_id = p2s.product_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN ab_manufacturers m 
              ON ( p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN ab_stock_statuses ss 
              ON ( p.stock_status_id = ss.stock_status_id 
                   AND ss.language_id = '1' ) 
       LEFT JOIN ab_products_to_categories p2c 
              ON ( p.product_id = p2c.product_id ) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_coloursproducts col 
               ON ( p.product_id = col.productid 
                    AND ( col.colourid = 2 
                           OR col.colourid = 3 
                           OR col.colourid = 5 
                           OR col.colourid = 8 
                           OR col.colourid = 10 ) ) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_useproducts tbluse 
               ON ( p.product_id = tbluse.productid 
                    AND ( tbluse.useid = 15 
                           OR tbluse.useid = 16 
                           OR tbluse.useid = 17 
                           OR tbluse.useid = 18 ) ) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_styleproducts style 
               ON ( p.product_id = style.productid 
                    AND ( style.styleid = 39 
                           OR style.styleid = 44 ) ) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_typeproducts type 
               ON ( p.product_id = type.productid 
                    AND ( type.typeid = 46 
                           OR type.typeid = 48 
                           OR type.typeid = 50 ) ) 
WHERE  p.status = '1' 
       AND p.date_available <= Now() 
       AND p2s.store_id = 0 
       AND p2c.category_id = 131 
GROUP  BY p.product_id 
ORDER  BY p.product_id DESC 
LIMIT  0, 8
```

Without the custom bits the query runs fine.

Comment: can you add indexes to the table?

Comment: Edit your question with an EXPLAIN of a large query

Comment: and your schema with indexes. I have a feeling it is page thrashing.

Comment: Added the full query, which is an Abantecart standard query but someone has added the extra bits

Comment: @Tom - I hope the edit didn't alter your message. The query you pasted appeared in only one line and was hard to read so I applied automatic formatting to it. I thought it made the post clearer. Feel free to rollback the change if you wish

Comment: Makes it much easier, thank you

Comment: It is usually "wrong" to include `col=const` in an `ON` clause.  Move them to `WHERE` and/or change to plain `JOIN`,

Comment: Major exception to that is LEFT OUTER JOINs.. Although I suspect in this circumstances on the INNER JOINs it is done for ease when building up dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that query, not sure the ORs are the problem themselves (although you could possibly make the code more compact by using and IN clause for each one). Rather I suspect that selecting more and more options results in more rows being returned. And this is causing problems with the sub queries in the SELECT clause.

Can you try the query with the sub queries removed from the SELECT clause and see the effect that has.

You can remove the sub queries quite easily.

```
SELECT *, 
       p.product_id, 
       Coalesce(sub1.price, p.price) AS final_price, 
       pd.name                       AS name, 
       m.name                        AS manufacturer, 
       ss.name                       AS stock, 
       sub0.rating, 
       sub0.review 
FROM   ab_products p 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT r.product_id,
            Avg(r.rating)  AS rating, 
            Count(rw.review_id) AS review 
    FROM   ab_reviews r 
    GROUP  BY r.product_id
) sub0
ON p.product_id = sub0.product_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT p2sp.product_id,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(p2sp.price ORDER  BY p2sp.priority ASC, p2sp.price ASC ), ',', 1) AS price
    FROM   ab_product_specials p2sp 
    WHERE  p2sp.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND ( p2sp.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR p2sp.date_start < NOW() ) 
    AND ( p2sp.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR p2sp.date_end > NOW() )
    GROUP BY p2sp.product_id
) sub1
ON p.product_id = sub1.product_id 
       LEFT JOIN ab_product_descriptions pd 
              ON ( p.product_id = pd.product_id 
                   AND pd.language_id = '1' ) 
       LEFT JOIN ab_products_to_stores p2s 
              ON ( p.product_id = p2s.product_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN ab_manufacturers m 
              ON ( p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN ab_stock_statuses ss 
              ON ( p.stock_status_id = ss.stock_status_id 
                   AND ss.language_id = '1' ) 
       LEFT JOIN ab_products_to_categories p2c 
              ON ( p.product_id = p2c.product_id ) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_coloursproducts col 
               ON ( p.product_id = col.productid 
                    AND ( col.colourid = 2 
                           OR col.colourid = 3 
                           OR col.colourid = 5 
                           OR col.colourid = 8 
                           OR col.colourid = 10 ) ) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_useproducts tbluse 
               ON ( p.product_id = tbluse.productid 
                    AND ( tbluse.useid = 15 
                           OR tbluse.useid = 16 
                           OR tbluse.useid = 17 
                           OR tbluse.useid = 18 ) ) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_styleproducts style 
               ON ( p.product_id = style.productid 
                    AND ( style.styleid = 39 
                           OR style.styleid = 44 ) ) 
       INNER JOIN tbl_typeproducts type 
               ON ( p.product_id = type.productid 
                    AND ( type.typeid = 46 
                           OR type.typeid = 48 
                           OR type.typeid = 50 ) ) 
WHERE  p.status = '1' 
       AND p.date_available <= Now() 
       AND p2s.store_id = 0 
       AND p2c.category_id = 131 
GROUP  BY p.product_id 
ORDER  BY p.product_id DESC 
LIMIT  0, 8
```

As an aside, when you read from ab_product_specials you are checking for the date_start and date_end to be 0000-00-00 (ie, dates), but also comparing them with NOW() which returns a date / time field. Are those fields date or date / time fields?

Answer (score 0):

My first though was to use `IN` to make the query eaier to read:

```
INNER JOIN tbl_coloursProducts col 
   ON p.product_id = col.productID AND col.colourID IN ( 2, 3, 5, 8, 10 )
```

Then I thought, I wonder if they are dynamically building SQL text to squirt into the database logic?! The optimizer is unlikely to do well at optimizing queries when they are constantly mutating in this way.

Consider a scratch table (pseudo code):

```
-- One time:
CREATE TABLE SratchColours ( colourID INT NOT NULL UNQIUE );

-- For each query:
DELETE FROM SratchColours;
INSERT INTO SratchColours VALUES ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 5 ), ( 8 ), ( 10 );
```

Now you dynamic list of values simply becomes just another join:

```
tbl_coloursProducts NATURAL JOIN SratchColours
```

(or you could use an inner join if you must!)

Now, having one base table for every concurrent user is probably not a great way to scale a system. Therefore, consider how to pass a bag of `colourID` values to the database logic (say, a stored proc), put them into a table (say, a temporary table), then join from there to your base tables.